# How would I find the Context Free Grammar for the complement of L = {a^n | n>= 0}? The alphabet is {a}.

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I am being asked to complement a language similar to $L = \{a^n\mid n \ge 0\}$. Then construct a context free grammar for that. As I understand, the complement of this is $L' = \{a^n\mid n \lt 0\}$. The part I am hung up on is the concept of $a^n$ with a negative $n$. If $a^3 = a\times a\times a$ and so on, how could one think of writing a a negative number of times? Does this concept even make sense? I also wonder if I am taking the complement incorrectly.

Comment: The concept makes sense  only for $n\ge 0$.

Comment: That is just the empty language, $\varnothing$.

Comment: Wouldn't the complement of $L$ be $\Sigma^* \backslash L$ where $\Sigma$ is the language's alphabet?

Comment: You need to edit the title :) $n < 0$ makes no sense in this context. The question is: CF grammar for complement of $\{a^n \mid n \ge 0\}$? No, negative exponents make no sense at all. *What is the alphabet?* If the alphabet is $\{a\}$ then the complement is........? (you figure it out) But if the alphabet contains symbols other than 'a', then ... what can you say?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. In the example I gave the alphabet would be {a} (the actual homework is just the same done on b^n as well with alphabet {a, b}. Is the problem a misunderstanding of taking the complement of this language?

Comment: Actually figured it out! Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

CFG for $\mathcal L=\{a^n|n \geq 0\}$:

Let's say thet $S$ is the start so:

$S\to aA|\varepsilon\\
A\to a|aA|\varepsilon$

Now from this CFG you can generate every word from your language e.g the word $z=aaa$

So we can derivate this wod:

$S\to aA\to A\to aaA \to aaaA \to \varepsilon$ and you can do the same for all $n$